# TensorFlow Lite: Is tensor string buffer format ASCII or UTF-8?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Are the strings stored in a .tflite tensor buffer in ASCII or UTF-8 format?

Answer (score 2):

The few TensorFlow Lite ops that deal with string can handle UTF-8 and adhere to the format described in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/string_util.h#L17

That is:

- 4 bytes specifying the number of strings in the tensor
- a section describing the length and location (offset) of each string inside the buffer, and the length of the buffer itself.
- a section containing the actual strings.